# Filepath: use same filepath on unix and winodws

Tags: linux, samba, path, remote

I am working on application which work on both unix and windows environment.
I have mapped my unix drive on windows using samba.

On cygwin:

```
 ls -l /remote
 /remote -> //samba1
```

when I try following command:

```
myExecutable /remote/fileloc/filename.txt
```

It's working fine in Unix but failing on windows during file opening.
If I give the following command on windows:

```
myExecutable //samba1/fileloc/filename.txt
```

It works fine.

Is there any way I can access with same path (`/remote/fileloc/filename.txt`) on both unix and windows?

I can change only in windows. Unix drive path I can't change.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use **relative pathnames.** E.g.,

```bash
myExecutable ../fileloc/filename.txt
```

will mean the same on both systems. Of course this syntax requires that the current directory of the invoking script (the script that contains the above line) should be on the same Windows drive letter as the filename. If not, I would just adopt solution 2:

A more general solution would be to add a bit of **conditional code** to your script, that checks which host or system you are on and sets a variable accordingly. Something like this:

```bash
if [ `hostname` == mylinuxbox ]
then
    BASEDIR=/remote
else
    BASEDIR=//samba
fi

myExecutable "$BASEDIR"/fileloc/filename.txt
```

Comment: adding conditional statement would be last option i would like to avoid them. Trying to find out if there is any better solution present.

Comment: Then use relative paths. If that's not an option, though, conditional statements are a great way to set up a system-independent environment for the main part of your code.